# Lyapunov's Direct Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

The following non linear system is given:
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1(t)&=x_2(t)\\
\dot{x}_2(t)&=-\frac{g}{l}\sin(x_1)-\frac{k}{m}x_2
\end{align}
Is asked to apply the Lyapunov's direct method in order to show that the origin is stable.
What I have done so far is to take the energy as Lyapunov function:
$$\dot{V}(x)=mgl(1-\cos(x_1))+\frac{m}{2}l^2x_2^2$$
for which I have the following properties:
$$V(0)=0$$
$$V(x)>0 \quad \forall x\neq0$$
The last property to check is that $\dot{V}(x)\leqslant0$ and, after some computations, I came out with this:
$$\dot{V}(x)=-l^2kx_2^2$$
Now my question is: as the derivative is negative with respect to $x_2$ but does not depend on $x_1$, can I conclude the Lyapunov stability of the origin?

Comment: What kind of stability do you want to show? Namely, there are a lot of different notions of stability, such as asymptotically-, exponentially-, Lyapunov- and BIBO- stable.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Sorry that’s my bad, I should show if the system is Lyapunov stable.

Comment: Yes, you've shown that $\dot V \leq 0$ for all $(x_1, x_2)$. The conditions that you have imply that the origin is Lyapunov stable (but not that it's asymptotically stable).

Comment: @Maxim are you sure? Even if $x_1$ is free? Because what I thought is that, as I don’t have any condition on $x_1$ I can not conclude even the Lyapunov stability.

Comment: $\dot V$ is a function of the vector $x$: $\dot V = (x_1, x_2) \mapsto - k l^2 x_2^2$.

Comment: Can a harmonic oscillator (i.e. a mass-spring system) be considered Lyapunov stable?

Comment: @Maxim ok perfect I got it now, thank you very much!